# What is the cheapest and smallest way to add USB ports to the Raspberry Pi Zero?

Tags: usb, pi-zero

What is the cheapest (under $15) and smallest way to add 1 more USB port to the Raspberry Pi Zero.

Comment: I have no idea about the price, but in terms of small, I find [this PiZeroHub](http://deluxecapacitor.com/projects/view/15) very neat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USB OTG [On the Go] Hubs. Like [this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/For-Samsung-3in1-Male-to-Female-Dual-Micro-USB-2-0-Host-OTG-Hub-Adapter-Cable-/371466012230?hash=item567d198646:g:84gAAOSwo6lWIgLh). I used this for another answer to a similar question [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38807/powered-usb-hub-for-pi-zero/38810#38810).

Comment: +1 though I would add a word of warning that the pi is unlikely to be able to power multiple devices.